# Do some countries officially limit the number of parties that can contest elections, to a number >1?

Tags: constitution, parties, parliament, comparative-politics, somaliland

Wikipedia says [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_Somaliland):

> The constitution of Somaliland only allows for the top three political parties to contest elections, to avoid the previous proliferation of clan-based parties in the 1960s.

Besides Somaliland, do some [other] countries (besides the trivial single-party ones) officially limit the number of parties that can contest elections to a fixed number (> 1)? (I'm not asking about vote-share [thresholds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_threshold) to enter parliament, that's a far more common method.)

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  There are a great many countries in which parties don't (formally) contest the election at all.  In the UK are just lots of local elections and voters vote for a candidate, not a party. There are also countries like China with a few licenced parties that are formally independent of the CCP, but in fact support it in all significant policies.  I don't think the UK nor China would fit the spirit of your question.

Comment: Afaik civilized countries solve this by that the Prime Minister needs approval of >=50% of the Parlament. You can get 20 parties in the Parlament if you wish to, but you can be PM only if you give enough back to at least 9 of them to vote you (normally they want to be part of the government for that, that is called coalition government).

Comment: It worth mentioning that basically no other country recognized the sovereignty of Somaliland, so it basically isn't a country and is instead a secessionist minded province of Somalia.

Comment: North Korea has more than one officially recognized political parties but only a few and in name only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any current examples, but Djibouti operated under a four-party limit from the adoption of the new constitution in 1992 until 2002, when President Guelleh introduced a full multiparty political system. The first new political party was founded in October of that year, the [Djibouti Union for Democracy and Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djibouti_Union_for_Democracy_and_Justice).

The four-party limit provision was approved in [a referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_Djiboutian_constitutional_referendum) held at the same time as the 1992 constitution was approved, with 97.9% of valid votes answering 'Yes' to the question "Do you approve the limitation of party politics to four parties?".

Comment: Either your knowledge is truly encyclopedic, or your google-fu is much better than mine!

Comment: @JamesK: anyhow, interesting that this is a regional thing. (Djibouti borders Somaliland.)